# What is the carbon footprint of a diamond?

Tags: materials, solid-state-chemistry, environmental-chemistry

I think it would be interesting and illuminating to calculate the carbon footprint (per carat) of diamond. The answer would undoubtedly be different for artificial (industrial grade) diamonds vs. natural ones. Is anyone out there familiar enough with either natural diamond mining and processing or the high-pressure process for making artificial diamonds to venture an answer to this question? Both surely involve expenditure of a considerable amount of energy.

Comment: Perhaps this question fits better on [Sustainability SE](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: I’d like to answer this. I found an answer on the inter-webs, at  https://www.cleanorigin.com/diamonds/#p=7